# Not repeated column in sql codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have a table `stock` where have the columns `id_stock, id_product_stock`. When I join the products with stock and if have more than one stock with the same product, this product its repeated in the return of the query. I don't want this product being repeat. Although I want do it just with SQL.

```
$this->db->join('products', 'products.id_products = stock.id_produtc_stock','left');
```

**Example:** if have three(3) data stock with the same `id_product_stock` the return will be in 3 results; I want the return be in just 1, because the return in the data of the stock have the same `id_product_stock`. Also if this return have more one `id_product_stock` different of the other.

I tried to change the tables in the query, but it returns the data in the same way.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text. And show us your current query.

Comment: seems a group by is missing, but show us code please and database schema/data

Comment: use `group_by` or `DISTINCT`. look [documentaion](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a group by:

```
 $this->db->group_by('id_product_stock');
```

Comment: this worked very well, I put this after the join and worked. So: $this->db->group_by('stock.id_product_stock'); THANKS FOR ALL

Answer (score 0):

Add this check if still happens, this will avoid having duplicate data in return results.

```
$this->db->distinct();
```